# Does the OS kill the UI when the android app runs for a long time?

Tags: android

I have an android application with 2 parts UI and Service, performing steps like this.

Step 1: Run the application.

Step 2: Press the phone power button to turn off the screen. Do not press the home button.

Step 3: For a long time (1 day, 2 days ..., 3 days)

Step 4: Press the phone power button to open the screen.

Then the application does not appear on the screen as usual, but needs to run again from the application icon or from the recent application screen. The service part is still alive. What is the cause, is it due to OS kill UI?